# Gitlab: Can not set relay address for email (state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol")

Tags: authentication, ssl, openssl, gitlab

This is what my `"/srv/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb"` looks like for `email` settings

```
################################
# GitLab email server settings #
################################
# see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/doc/settings/smtp.md#smtp-settings
# Use smtp instead of sendmail/postfix.

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "corp-myorg-com.mail.outlook.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
# gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "smtp user"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "smtp password"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "example.com"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none' # Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert', see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_path'] = "/etc/ssl/certs"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

When I try to sign up from GitLab web page, I see in logs that

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started POST "/users" for 172.32.1.111 at 2015-09-10 04:50:47 +0000
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"Harit Himanshu", "username"=>"harit", "email"=>"harit@myorg.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Completed 200 OK in 364ms (Views: 44.7ms | ActiveRecord: 24.1ms)

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.32.1.111 - - [10/Sep/2015:04:50:48 +0000] "POST /users HTTP/1.1" 200 2223 "http://172.16.205.153:8080/users/sign_in" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36"

==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
2015-09-10_04:50:56.62636 2015-09-10T04:50:56.626Z 447 TID-elbtk Devise::Async::Backend::Sidekiq JID-24a487b2ee95a069f6783b43 INFO: start

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==

Sent mail to harit@myorg.com (331.0ms)

==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
2015-09-10_04:50:57.01071 2015-09-10T04:50:57.010Z 447 TID-elbtk Devise::Async::Backend::Sidekiq JID-24a487b2ee95a069f6783b43 INFO: fail: 0.384 sec
2015-09-10_04:50:57.01139 2015-09-10T04:50:57.011Z 447 TID-elbtk WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"mailer", "class"=>"Devise::Async::Backend::Sidekiq", "args"=>["confirmation_instructions", "User", "4", "H7fU4LytjadCSCMyJv-S", {}], "jid"=>"24a487b2ee95a069f6783b43", "enqueued_at"=>1441859975.09268, "error_message"=>"SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol", "error_class"=>"OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError", "failed_at"=>1441859975.4031353, "retry_count"=>5, "retried_at"=>1441860657.0101695}
2015-09-10_04:50:57.01141 2015-09-10T04:50:57.011Z 447 TID-elbtk WARN: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol
2015-09-10_04:50:57.01145 2015-09-10T04:50:57.011Z 447 TID-elbtk WARN: /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:586:in `connect'
2015-09-10_04:50:57.01146 /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:586:in `tlsconnect'
2015-09-10_04:50:57.01146 /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:554:in `do_start'
2015-09-10_04:50:57.01147 /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
2015-09-10_04:50:57.01147 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
```

What is the issue, I am able to use this relay address in production with other projects.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Here's my standard response for troubleshooting these issues. It will help you isolate the issue to the client (likely because its Ruby) or server (possible because its Microsoft with all their down level TLS gear). Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname>`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue with Gitlab CE 8.11.4. I found that these settings worked:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
```